# Simplest way to implement a sliding overlay panel in android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-framelayout

I need simplest way to implement a sliding overlay panel for my app.
Here is what I want to do:

I have a grid view of images in my main activity, when user clicks a Image a sliding overlay drops from top of screen to up to half way showing details of Image and partially hiding contents of grid view, I have searched quite bit and found these articles;

- [Using FrameLayout](http://blog.neteril.org/blog/2013/10/10/framelayout-your-best-ui-friend/),
- [SlidingUp Library](https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel)
- Using fragments

but I do not want to use a library for this simple task as it may be a overkill.
So can somebody please share some example to implement it using Framelayout or fragment in minimalistic way possible.

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/Ali-Rezaei/SlidingDrawer which makes it possible to slide from any side by few lines of code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a `RelativeLayout` that has a view that's outside of the screen and move it with an `ObjectAnimator` that sets the view's `translateY` property.

```
ObjectAnimator objectAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(yourLayout, "TranslationY", 200 );
objectAnimator.start();
```

This will animate the move of the layout container.

Comment: ObjectAnimator Added in API level 11, this solution cannot work for the old Android OS version.
Simply, you can use a translate animation in your res/anim folder and call it from your activity.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this

https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu

If you are using Actionbar then you can use this code:

```
setTheme(theme.whatever);
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR_OVERLAY);
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.content);
getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.color));
```